# Java FX - Loading multiple webpages in webView at a time

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I have a webView project with javafx, when the program starts it opens 5 different tabs each one loading a different webpage. The problem is that it only loads one page at a time, for example it loads tab 3 and waits until its fully loaded then moves onto tab 4 to fully load that etc. I am needing the webview to load all of the tabs at the same time ensuring they are all loaded around the same time instead of them loading 1 by 1. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this. In my quick test, multiple web pages seem to load concurrently.

Comment: Could you post your example ? In my case, it loads sequentially

Comment: See [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/531b9d4894f3746f67c0)

Comment: Oh yeah, I did not load enough websites, they seemed to load in the order of the `load` call, but it appears that changing the order of the calls does not change the order of apparition. You're right

Comment: The important thing is to check the state of the load worker: all of them go to `RUNNING` (i.e. loading) before any finish (at least, over my network connection...).